# Call to a member function getStepName() on null

Tags: php, symfony, workflow

I am using Lexik Workflow Bundle to manage workflows. I have created a simple workflow in `video_derivative_workflow.yml` and put the following into my admin class:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function getWorkflowName()
{
    return 'video_derivative_workflow';
}
```

... and I now find that I'm getting the following fatal error:

> Call to a member function getStepName() on null

Anyone know what this means in the context of this bundle?

Comment: This means that, in $obj->getStepName, $obj is not really an object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12769983/61795)

Comment: Sure that's the correct code? Can't find `getStepName()` anywhere

Comment: Way too little information. At least do some basic investigation. Also, if it is an sf3 project don't use this bundle, it is deprecated. Use the component.

Comment: Yup, it turned out that this was a method call outside of the bundle. Sorry 'bout that.